# Explanation percentage of emissions for $\alpha$ / $\beta$ / $\gamma$ decay

Tags: nuclear-physics, radiation

[image: Table Of Decaying Isotopes]

For Cobalt and Americium, why is the alpha decay for Americium not $100\%$ but $85\%$ & $13\%$ whereas for Cobalt it is all $100\%$

Comment: Odd table, given the multiple “100%” gamma emissions for several isotopes. And I’d expect a real nuclear physics table to list energy in keV or MeV. But it is often the case that the daughter product has multiple possible energy levels to decay into, yielding different emitted alpha energies (and usually a gamma to make up the difference).

Comment: Briefly, $\gamma$ decays don't change the number of protons and neutrons. They just change whether the nucleus is in an excited quantum state. The table _might_ be communicating that the given nucleus is often created in an excited quantum state after being produced in a decay from another nucleus, and it always goes to a lower state by emitting a photon (or two) before it does its beta decay. Or maybe its just saying "if it's in the excited state it will decay by photon emission, and if not beta." I'd agree this is poorly communicated and doesn't make sense in the form presented here.

Answer (score 2):

You have to be careful in accepting everything as the complete characteristic.

The energy levels for the two nuclei are shown below which illustrates my point that in your table only the most probable decays are listed.

[image]

You may care to have a look at [Chart of Nuclides](https://www-nds.iaea.org/relnsd/vcharthtml/VChartHTML.html) which list even more energy levels and the corresponding transitions.